# JS Using prototype function in prototype

Tags: javascript

Hey i'am writing a little object :

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angle = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    this.radius = Math.atan(y / x);
};
Point.prototype = {
    constructor: Point,
    calculateRadius: function(x, y) {
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    },
    calculateAngle: function(x, y) {
        return Math.atan(y / x);
    },
    cartToRad: function(x, y) {
        this.radius = calculateRadius(x, y);
        this.angle = calculateAngle(x, y);
    }
};
var coords = new Point(0, 0);
coords.cartToRad(5, 0.523);
```

And that throw an error:

```
ReferenceError: calculateRadius is not defined.
```

Is it possible to use prototype functions in other prototype functions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference them as properties of `this`, just like any other property.